# How can online code editor Scastie read an input file?

Tags: scala

I have a need to pass a very big input file to [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org). I mean how can Scastie which is online code editor read a file which is available at my local machine, for example

```
val lines = sc.textfile("....mdb/u.data")
```

Comment: Maybe you should set up an appropriate development environment in your machine rather than using a site which was designed just for sharing small snippets.

Comment: Makes sense what you said,but my machine is already occupied,and I don't want to spend money on cloud stuff ,they charge heavu both GCP and AWS to use scala and spark ,for me   learning  the Spark concepts is important rather than over spending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some asked this on the team's [Gitter](https://gitter.im/scalacenter/scastie?at=5954bab55a1ab55f6438349d) channel.

The Scastie team member first asked how big the file is, then recommended to put it in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/discover) on Github and to use the raw url to read it in.

This works only for small files. The limits of files on Gist are explained in their [Developer Guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/).

> If you need the full contents of the file, you can make a GET request to the URL specified by raw_url. **Be aware that for files larger than ten megabytes**, you'll need to clone the gist via the URL provided by git_pull_url.

So 10 MB is your limit. Also note that you can't use a `SparkContext`(denoted by `sc` in your question) without identifying the library to the online environment.

To do that, you'll have to add the SBT dependency.

- Navigate to `Build Settings` on the left part of the interface.
- Set the `Scala Version` to a version compatible with the Spark we'll choose, in our case 2.11.12.
- Under `Extra Sbt Configuration` place the following dependencies:

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3",
       "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
    )
```

You won't be able to read url content directly using `sc.textFile`, that is only for reading local/HDFS text files. You'll have to get the content first, wrangle it into shape and get a `DataFrame` out of it.

The answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29741462/894641) describes how to access a web url using [Source](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source.html) from the Scala Standard Library.

At the request of the OP, here's an [implementation](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kfkhalili/sHLwMzFZS2C7LCXVhZ8XYA/74) on scastie.

Comment: hey this is the Url which contains data ,how can I make a GET request to  the  raw_url ,URL is this --> http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.data

Comment: @CarolynCordeiro  I edited the answer to link to an example based on your given file.

Comment: could you please reply on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821106/scastie-rendering-compiler-error-as-value-countbyvalue-is-not-a-member-of-org-a

Comment: I left you a comment there.

Comment: one more question i have asked there please have a look