# Scastie rendering compiler error as "value countByValue is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String]"

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi i am trying to find ratings histogram using scastie program...here is the implementation

sbet settings in scastie

```
        scalacOptions ++= Seq(
          "-deprecation",
          "-encoding", "UTF-8",
          "-feature",
          "-unchecked"
        )

            libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
              "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3",
              "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3"
            )
```

actual code in scastie

```
                    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
                    import org.apache.spark._
                    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
                    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
                    import org.apache.log4j._


                        object TestApp extends App {
                      lazy implicit val spark = 
                      SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("spark_test").getOrCreate()
                      
                      import spark.implicits._ // Required to call the .toDF function later
                      
                      val html = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml- 
     
                      100k/u.data").mkString // Get all rows as one string
                      val seqOfRecords = html.split("\n") // Split based on the newline characters
                                     .filter(_ != "") // Filter out any empty lines
                                     .toSeq // Convert to Seq so we can convert to DF later
                                     .map(row => row.split("\t")) 
                                     .map { case Array(f1,f2,f3,f4) => (f1,f2,f3,f4) } 
                      
                      val df = seqOfRecords.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") 
                      
                      val ratings = df.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
                      
                      

                    // Count up how many times each value (rating) occurs
                    val results = ratings.countByValue()

                    // Sort the resulting map of (rating, count) tuples
                    val sortedResults = results.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)

                    // Print each result on its own line.
                    sortedResults.foreach(println)

                      spark.close() 
                    }
```

Error getting in scastie

value countByValue is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String]

can someone help in deubgging[image]

===========================================
Revised code giving different error in Scastie now

```
                    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:136)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:745)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:704)
                        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:713)
                        at TestApp$.delayedEndpoint$TestApp$1(main.scala:22)
                        at TestApp$delayedInit$body.apply(main.scala:4)
                        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
                        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
                        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
                        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
                        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
                        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
                        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
                        at TestApp$.main(main.scala:4)
                        at TestApp.main(main.scala)
                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                        at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:115)
                        at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:79)
                        at sbt.Run.$anonfun$runWithLoader$4(Run.scala:92)
                        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
                        at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
                        at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:257)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.8
                        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
                        at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
                        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:751)
                        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
                        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
                        ... 40 more
```

here is updated code in scastie

```
                import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
                import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

                object TestApp extends App {
                  lazy implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("spark_test").getOrCreate()
                  
                  import spark.implicits._ // Required to call the .toDF function later
                  
                  val html = scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-100k/u.data").mkString // Get all rows as one string
                  val seqOfRecords = html.split("\n") // Split based on the newline characters
                                 .filter(_ != "") // Filter out any empty lines
                                 .toSeq // Convert to Seq so we can convert to DF later
                                 .map(row => row.split("\t")) // Split each line on tab character to make an Array of 4 String each
                                 .map { case Array(f1,f2,f3,f4) => (f1,f2,f3,f4) } // Convert that Array[String] into Array[(String, String, String, String)] 
                  
                  val df = seqOfRecords.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") // Give whatever column names you want
                  
                  df.select("col3").groupBy("col3").count.sort(col("count").desc).show()

                  spark.close() // don't forget to close(), otherwise scastie won't let you create another session so soon.
                }
```

Comment: What is the line `val ratings = df.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))` trying to achieve?

Comment: The thing is, when you map through the `df`, you are accessing each `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` object, e.g. `df.first` is `[196,242,3,881250949]`. You can turn that to a `String`, but there are no `\t` (tab character) to split by, so it will simply return one `String` as is in an `Array[String]` with only one element, so accessing the second element returns an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @kfkhalili  that line of code does this i.e.  convert each line to a string ,split it out by tabs,and extract the third field,
The file format is userID,movieID,rating,Timestamp,could you tell me if countByValue is not possible in this code?

Comment: Take a look at the answer. It shows you what's wrong and how to get what you want (I think).

Comment: @kfkhalili thank you so much for you responses if you can see the latest code of scastie in question ,the error got changed

Comment: @kfkhalili looks like Scastie doesnt likes ```df.select("col3").groupBy("col3").count.sort(col("count").desc).show()```

Comment: Yes. It’s a package conflict. Take a look at my answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of your question: So the main issue in your code is the attempt to split by tab `\t`. Your records don't contain any tabs, like I've explained in my comment.

> The thing is, when you map through the `df`, you are accessing each `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` object, e.g. `df.first` is `[196,242,3,881250949]`. You can turn that to a `String`, but there are no `\t` (tab character) to split by, so it will simply return one `String` as is in an `Array[String]` with only one element, so accessing the second element returns an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here's a demonstration:

```scala
// We get the first row and brute force convert it toString()
df.head.toString
//res21: String = [196,242,3,881250949] <- See? No tab anywhere

df.head.toString.split("\t")
//res22: Array[String] = Array([196,242,3,881250949]) <- Returns the string as is in an Array

res22(0)
//res24: String = [196,242,3,881250949] <- First Element

res22(1)
//java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 <- No second (or third) element found, hence the "out of bounds" exception.
//  ... 55 elided
```

I've understood from your comment that you are trying to get the third column. The beauty of using a `DataFrame` is that you can simply [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#select(col:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) the column you want by name. You can then [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupBy(col1:String,cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) it (this returns a [RelationalGroupedDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html)) and use the [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#count():org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method to aggregate.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
df.select("col3").groupBy("col3").count.sort(col("count").desc).show()
//+----+-----+
//|col3|count|
//+----+-----+
//|   4|34174|
//|   3|27145|
//|   5|21201|
//|   2|11370|
//|   1| 6110|
//+----+-----+
```

---

Second part of your question: It seems like Scastie loads a newer version of `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` than what Spark 2.4.3 uses, so while Scastie appears to use version `2.9.6`, Spark 2.4.3 uses an older version: [`2.6.7`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/pom.xml).

The only way I could get it to work was to use a newer version of Spark and Scala. Spark 3.0.1 uses [`2.10.0`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/pom.xml).

Under Build Settings:

- Set `Scala Version` to `2.12.10`.
- Set Extra Sbt Configuration library dependencies:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1"
)
```

It doesn't perform as well, the browser hangs and sometimes it times out. I guess Scastie is not yet optimized for this version.

Edit: Actually after I silenced the logging, [it works much better now](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kfkhalili/mXNLQrWEQnyocrqdzq5NJg/38)!

BUT still... **You really should install Spark on your local computer**.

Comment: request you to  have a look at updated revised code and error in original question and provide resolution what code change is required

Comment: looks like Scastie doesnt likes ```df.select("col3").groupBy("col3").count.sort(col("count").desc).show()```

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get to the `ratings` variable you are working with a Spark structure called a Dataset. You can look at the documentation describing what it can and cannot do [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset). It doesn't have a method called `countByValue` which is why you get the error you are seeing.

Everything you've got makes sense until you get to this line:

```
val ratings = df.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2))
```

This will currently generate an error.

If you go back to the `df` variable, you have a table that will look kind of like this:

```
+----+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|     col4|
+----+----+----+---------+
| 196| 242|   3|881250949|
| 186| 302|   3|891717742|
|  22| 377|   1|878887116|
| 244|  51|   2|880606923|
| 166| 346|   1|886397596|
+----+----+----+---------+
```

You can run the command `df.show()` to look a sample of what is in the dataset. From there I think you are wanting an operation that looks a bit like `groupBy`. Take a look at some [examples of this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/using-groupby-on-dataframe/) to see where to go next.

Comment: val ratings = df.map(x => x.toString().split("\t")(2)) that line of code does this --> convert each line to a string ,split it out by tabs,and extract the third field,
The file format is userID,movieID,rating,Timestamp,could you tell me if countByValue is not possible in this code?